# FSharp Charting change data point label font size

Tags: charts, f#, fsharpchart

Using F# Charting I am able to change axis label font sizes with

```
    chart |> Chart.WithArea.AxisX(LabelStyle = myStyle)
```

however have not found a way to change data point label font sizes

```
    let myChart = Chart.Line prices |> Chart.WithDataPointLables(Label = "hello")
```

created as above.

Any know how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be supported directly `FSharp.Charting` but the library does provide a hole through its abstraction so you can access the underlying chart representation and do whatever you want to it. Assuming that you're running this on Windows with `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`, which the library uses by default, then you can do this:

```
open FSharp.Charting

Chart.Line [1; 2; 3]
|> Chart.WithDataPointLabels(Label = "hello")
|> fun c -> c.ApplyToChart(fun c ->
    c.Series.[0].Font <- System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", float32 28))
```